# Keep ScrollView position when clicking a tab inside (which refresh data inside)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

scrollview - content view - 1) image, 2) tab, 3) stack view

Above is my storyboard arrangement. **The tabs are actually collection view.** Below the tab, there is **stack view** *(which also inside the content view)*. When I click each of the tabs, I **send the index of selected tab** at **didSelect**. It will call the **refreshData** function which have this flow: The **current subviews** inside the stack view **will be removed**  (using *vc.mainStack.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })*) and will **reload another subviews according to the index** of the selected tab. The **position of the image will remain the same**, which is at the top of the page. However, every time I click the tab, the screen will always scroll to top. How can I keep the scroll position (before I click another tab) so that when I click new tab, it will remain on the same scroll position?

```
self.yContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
```

already add above code inside scrollViewDidScroll and

```
vc.scrollView.contentOffset.y = self.yContentOffset
```

add above code after remove all subviews in the stack, then i call the new data(for subviews). Also tried adding the code after calling the new subviews, but both doesn't work. Do anyone knows the logic on how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more information... When you say *"tabs"* what do you mean? Are those just buttons arranged to look like tabs? Are you removing the stack view's current `.arrangedSubviews` and adding the new ones at the same time? Or, because you say *"then i call the new data(for subviews)"* do you mean you're calling a separate operation that retrieves data and *then* adds the new subviews?

Comment: Hi @DonMag, I'm sorry for the lack of information. I just edit my question. Hope you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the issue is that the UI is being "refreshed" between the point where you remove the current subviews and when you add the new subviews. So your `mainStack` becomes very short, resulting in the content view not being tall enough to require scrolling, and your scroll view adjusts itself accordingly.

Your options are to either wait remove the subviews until you have your new subviews, and remove / add in the same func, or replace the subviews with a clear "placeholder" view.

The second option could look like this:

```
func replaceViewsWithPlaceholderView() -> Void {

    // get an array of the current views in the stack
    let viewsToRemove = mainStack.arrangedSubviews

    // create a clear view
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .clear

    // needs a width
    v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    // constrain the height of the "place holder" view to the current height of the stack view
    v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: mainStack.frame.height).isActive = true

    // add the "place holder" view to the stack
    mainStack.addArrangedSubview(v)

    // remove the views that were in the stack
    viewsToRemove.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Then in your func that adds new subviews based on the selected tab, first:

```
    // remove the "place holder" view
    mainStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

followed by (probably a `.forEach` loop) adding the new subviews to `main.Stack`.

Of course, if you have scrolled so your "tabs" are at the top of the scroll view, and "tab B" doesn't have enough subviews to require scrolling, the scroll view will again adjust - but only to the point where the bottom of the content view is at the bottom of the scroll view.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I arranged your code according to my need and it works! :)